# How to display a picture from a database in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I understand that this is a stupid question and on the Internet you can find examples of how to do this, but basically I found some too confusing code where I didn't understand anything ...
I have a blog database on the localhost, I successfully upload all the information for the post (name, date, text and picture) there. But I generally can't figure out how to display it from there. Maybe someone will not be too lazy and show at least a part of the code or the idea itself ... Here I have a controller where I load information into the database

```
@PostMapping("addArticle")
public String postAddArticle(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user, Date timeArticle, @RequestParam String title, String author,
                             @RequestParam String anons, @RequestParam String text,
                             @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Model model) {
    Byte[] bArray = null;

    author = user.getUsername();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    timeArticle = calendar.getTime();

    try {
        bArray = new Byte[file.getBytes().length];
        int i = 0;
        for(byte b : file.getBytes()){
            bArray[i++] = b;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Post post = new Post(title,timeArticle, author, anons, text, bArray );
    post.setTitle(title);
    post.setTimeArticle(timeArticle);
    post.setAuthor(author);
    post.setAnons(anons);
    post.setText(text);
    post.setImage(bArray);
    postRepository.save(post);

    return "redirect:/adminPage";
}
```

The code works and everything is successfully added to the database, including the image. Tell me how to display it with thymeleaf in the img tag now?

Comment: Just a side note - dont store images in the database.

Comment: and where should I store it? and why it is impossible to store in the database?I really don't know, I'm a newbie

Comment: Probably on the harddrive, cloud service maybe. All depends on the deployment but it is usually stored as any other file resource.

Comment: why can't you store it in the database? And if I store these pictures on my hard drive and somehow display these pictures on the local host, then how can people see them if I upload my project to the github and they download it to check how everything works ...

Comment: The same way that DB will be exposed. Local storage is local to the application deployment, not always your workstation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a web application, normally you would add images to resources folder and these images will then be access via the application, if this suits you refer this:
[images as static resources](https://memorynotfound.com/adding-static-resources-css-javascript-images-thymeleaf/). So once this application get packaged and extracted after deployment, images paths will be resolved and can be seen on browsers.

If you so want to store images in the database, you could try saving them as base64 encoded strings in the database, for that you could use this:
[base64 conversion](https://www.baeldung.com/java-base64-image-string)

Comment: @Deniss Zadorozhniy, since you are a new user, I forgot to tell you, but you have accepted the answer, this way you can grow your network here and reputation